# Accessing Json information

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a .json file that I am having difficulty accessing certain information from. I am using React to contextualize.
In this case I would like to access "toppings".

```
[    
 {
    "topping": "pineapple and cheese",
    "size": "medium"
 },
 {
    "topping": "spinich",
    "size": "small"
 }
]
```

With the following code in pizzaData I am able to see all the information from the .json.

```
class Inf extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
        pizzaData: data
      }
    }
    renderList(data){
      return(
        <ul>{Object.keys(this.state.pizzaData).map(thing =><li>{thing}</li>)}</ul>
      )
    }
    render() {
      console.log(this.state.pizzaData)
      return (
        <div>
        <h1> Chose your seat</h1>
        <div>{this.renderList(this.state.pizzaData)}</div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

However if I try to do something like

```
pizzaData: data.topping
```

it comes back undefined.

How could I access the data?

PS. Currently there is an error in the console of "Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop." This error hasn't caused any issues as of yet as I know but it may be why I am having the current issue.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. Yes, the real Json has that I will add that to the question.

Comment: Your code is a little bit confusing... I see you are passing in `data` to your `renderList()` method, you however are not using that parameter but rather you have referenced `this.state.pizzaData`

Secondly are trying to access the key or the value of the key in your array

Comment: That use of the word data is arbitrary. If I change it to say renderList(pizza) instead it has no impact on the output.

Comment: Then it defeats the essence of having `this.renderList(this.state.pizzaData)` in your `render()` method. Anyways, take a look at @illiteratewriter answer

Comment: @Mark The original question did not have an id; that is why i did not add id and instead used index.

Comment: @illiteratewriter. Sure. Seen your comment on your answer on having unique keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through `pizzaData` (which is an array) using any of the usual array looping or mapping features; for instance, you might use `map` to create an `li` for each entry:

```
const list = this.state.pizzaData.map((entry, index) => {
    return <li key={index}>...details here...</li>;
});
```

Note the `key={index}` there, to give each row in the list a unique key.

Within that, you'd access `size` and `topping` on `entry` to access them. So for instance:

```
const list = this.state.pizzaData.map((entry, index) => {
    return <li key={index}>Size: {entry.size}, Topping: {entry.topping}</li>;
});
```

Which would make `renderList` look like this:

```
renderList(data){
    const list = this.state.pizzaData.map((entry, index) => {
        return <li key={index}>Size: {entry.size}, Topping: {entry.topping}</li>;
    });
    return(
        <ul>{list}</ul>
    )
}
```

(You don't need the `list` constant, you could embed the call to `map` in the `<ul>...</ul>`, but it's handy for staying sane, and for debugging, and will get optimized away at runtime.)

Live Example:

```js
var data = [    
   {
      "topping": "pineapple and cheese",
      "size": "medium"
   },
  {
      "topping": "spinich",
      "size": "small"
  }
];

class Inf extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            pizzaData: data
        }
    }
    renderList(data){
        const list = this.state.pizzaData.map((entry, index) => {
            return <li key={index}>Size: {entry.size}, Topping: {entry.topping}</li>;
        });
        return(
            <ul>{list}</ul>
        )
    }
    render() {
        //console.log(this.state.pizzaData)
        return (
            <div>
            <h1> Chose your seat</h1>
            <div>{this.renderList(this.state.pizzaData)}</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Inf />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Inf extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
        pizzaData: [ {
    "topping": "pineapple and cheese",
    "size": "medium"

 },
 {
    "topping": "spinich",
    "size": "small"
 }]
      }
    }
    renderList(data){
      const listItems = data.map((item, index) =><li key={index}>{item.topping}</li>)
      console.log(data);
      return(
        <ul>{listItems}</ul>
      )
    }
    render() {
      console.log(this.state.pizzaData)
      return (
        <div>
        <h1> Chose your seat</h1>
        <div>{this.renderList(this.state.pizzaData)}</div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

Here, the listItems is an array created by looping through the item array and taking the topping of each item. Also the `key={index}` is the key which is to be used by react for it to understand which items has been moved, deleted or changed.

It is not recomended to use index as key, Keys should be unique. Always try to have a unique key such as id for each object.

Comment: Code dumps are not *useful* answers. Say *what* you did, and *why*.

Comment: I haven't added key in this. Refer https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html to add key.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry; and okay.

Answer (score 0):

It is `data[1].topping` since it is an array of objects. And about keys

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity

refer [this page](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) for more on keys

Comment: That would get the information for one topping but how would I be able to receive the information from all the toppings (the real .json is quite big).

Comment: You can loop through the json data. Your json file is basically an array of objects, so you can loop through all the data. Got it?

Comment: You mean with a for each with the [] being a variable? But how would you implement that in this scenario since its react?